# Solve $yy' + x =\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ - Substitution for Diff Eqs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem

$$yy' + x = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$

I wanted to know if my work and answer are correct.

Let $v = x^{2} + y^{2}. v' = 2x + 2yy'$

$$ \frac{v'}{2} = x + yy'$$

Substituting everything in gives me:

$$\frac{v'}{2} = \sqrt{v}$$

From here it becomes a separable equation:

$$\frac{dv}{\sqrt{v}} = 2dx$$

$$2\sqrt{v} = 2x +C$$

Subbing in $x^2 + y^2$ back gives me: $$2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 2x + C$$

And now if at this point my work is correct, we just solve for $y$ right?

$$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = x + \frac{C}{2}$$
Square both sides:

$$x^2 + y^2 = \bigg(x+\frac{C}{2}\bigg)^{2}$$

$$y^2 = \bigg(x+\frac{C}{2}\bigg)^{2} - x^2$$

And finally,

$$y = \pm\sqrt{\bigg(x+\frac{C}{2}\bigg)^{2} - x^2}$$

Comment: There is a very easy way to check if you got the correct solution: plug it into the original differential equation and see if it holds. Also, you need to be careful when solving the separable equation $$\frac{v'}{2}=\sqrt v$$. You divided both sides by $\sqrt v$, but what if $v=0$? This means there is an extra solution $v=0$, which becomes $x^2+y^2=0$.

Comment: How do I plug in $$yy' + x = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$ into my answer?

Comment: You're thinking about it in reverse. Substitute your answer for each $y$ in the original differential equation and substitute its derivative into each $y'$ in the original differential equation.

Comment: It's too late to edit my comment, but I just realized that my "extra solution" $x^2+y^2=0$ is not really a solution because it's just the point $(0,0)$ (assuming you're not dealing with complex numbers or anything). But my point is still valid in that you need to consider the case where $v=0$. It just turns out that it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: I just want to know if my work and answer was correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct.

At $$y^2 = \bigg(x+\frac{C}{2}\bigg)^{2} - x^2$$

You may simplify $$ y^2 = \bigg(x+\frac{C}{2}\bigg)^{2} - x^2=Cx+\frac {C^2}{4}$$

Which is a family of parabolas.$$y^2 =Cx+\frac {C^2}{4}.$$

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed and what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.